# General formula to compute the exponent of the symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, permutations, exponentiation, symmetric-groups

Someone has already asked [whether an exponent less than $n!$ is possible for a symmetric group $S_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493259/whats-the-smallest-exponent-to-give-the-identity-in-s-n).  It has been answered that it is for $n \ge 4$.

I would like to know if there is a general formula to determine the exponent of $S_n$.

Comment: The answer is already given in the answers to that other question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each prime $p\le n$ we have to decide what is the maximal $k$ such that $S_n$ contains an element of order $p^k$. We may assume that such an element has only a single cycle because disjoint cycles combine only by taking the lcm, which does not "help" for prime powers. Thus the maximal $k$ is given by the bound $p^k\le n$. Hence the exponent of $S_n$ is
$$\prod_{p\le n}p^{\lfloor \ln n/\ln p\rfloor}.$$

Comment: what is the purpose of $\lfloor \ln n/\ln p\rfloor$ here?

Comment: @Omar: this is clearly explained in the previous sentence: it's the largest $k$ such that $S_n$ contains an element of order $p^k$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I am afraid I do not understand why $k = \lfloor \ln n/\ln p\rfloor$. I understand that we have to do something related to calculating the  lcm of the orders of all $p$'s.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Does $k = \lfloor \ln n/\ln p\rfloor$ have anything to do with the prime number theorem?

Comment: @Omar: no. It's just the largest $k$ such that $p^k \le n$. To get there from here, take the natural log of both sides, then remember that $k$ is an integer.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, so the exponent of $S_5$ is $2^{\lfloor \ln 5/\ln 2\rfloor} . 3^{\lfloor \ln 5/\ln 3\rfloor} . 5^{\lfloor \ln 5/\ln 5\rfloor} = 2^2 . 3 . 5 = 60$. Right?

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302278/mathrmlcm1-2-3-ldots-n