# Element of Largest Order in $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, symmetric-groups

> What is the largest order of an element in the group of permutations of $5$ objects?

Let $\sigma \in S_5$ be arbitrary. We know that $\sigma = \sigma_1...\sigma_k$, where the $\sigma_i$'s are disjoint cycles of some length. We want to maximize $|\sigma| = lcm(|\sigma_1|,...,|\sigma_k|)$, where $|\sigma_i|$ is the order of the permutation $\sigma_i$, which is just its length since it is a cycle. If any of the lengths are the same, then the lcm will be the same, so we may take each $\sigma_i$ to have a different length in our attempt to maximize $|\sigma|$. This leaves us with four different lengths (I am excluding $1$). Thus $\sigma = \sigma_1 ... \sigma_4$; however, as we shall see, it is not possible for $\sigma$ to be a product of 4 disjoint cycles if we are maximizing their lengths. If $\sigma_1$ is a 5-cycle, then none of the 5 numbers will appear in any of the other cycles, and so $\sigma = \sigma_1$ which implies $|\sigma| = 5$. If $\sigma_1$ is a 4-cycle, then 4 of the 5 numbers appear in it, leaving only number left $\sigma_1$ and none to ther others. But this would make $\sigma_2$ and the rest the identity, so that $\sigma = \sigma_1$. In this case $|\sigma| = 4$. Finally, if $\sigma_1$ is a 3-cycle, then $\sigma_2$ can have the rest of the numbers which makes it a 2-cycle. In this case, $|\sigma| = lcm(3,2) = 6$.  By symmetry, the rest of the cases are equivalent, and so the maximum value is $6$.

How does that sound?

Comment: It's correct, but a little lengthy for me.

Comment: Your logic appears to be correct. Good job!

Comment: @Bernard Is it my writing that is lengthy or did I introduce unnecessary steps in my solution? Because if there is a more direct solution, I am interested in knowing it.

Comment: For me, it's mainly your writing: some details ore obvious. Also, in $S_5$, if you don't write the $1$-cycles, a permutation is the product of at most *two* cycles, of orders $2,2$, or $2,3$. This observation should shorten the writing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could be explicit and argue as follows:

The partitions of $5$ are
$$\eqalign{
\mbox{type} & \to \mbox{lcm} \cr
5 & \to  5 \cr
4+1 & \to  4 \cr
3+2 & \to  6 \ * \cr
3+1+1 & \to  3 \cr
2+2+1 & \to  2 \cr
2+1+1+1 & \to  2 \cr
1+1+1+1+1 & \to  1 \cr
}$$

Comment: Hello, it seems to me that the element of highest order in $S_n$  in the largest partition of $k$ where $k\leq n$ into relatively prime numbers, is this corret or where may I find information about it, thanks in advance.

Comment: @muhammad, not quite. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576417/general-formula-to-compute-the-exponent-of-the-symmetric-group-s-n and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function

Comment: Landau's funcions is more to what I was referring to, in the first link I'm not really sure what "exponent" means, for example in $S_5$ the element of largest order is 6, however the formula in the 1st link gives 60, furthermore the bound of $g(n)$ (Landau's function) gives $g(5)\leq 6.2$, likewise for $S_{10}$, $g(10)\leq 39.5$ but formula in link 1 gives a number greater than 2000.

Comment: So yes, Landau's function is what I was asking for, I'll look up at the references of that wikipedia article, thanks!

Comment: Oh don't bother now, so the exponent of $S_n$ in that post is the largest $k$ such that $a^{k}=e$ and $k<n!$.

Answer (score 0):

> Let $\sigma \in S_5$ be arbitrary. We know that $\sigma = \sigma_1...\sigma_k$, where the $\sigma_i$'s are disjoint cycles of some length. We want to maximize $|\sigma| = lcm(|\sigma_1|,...,|\sigma_k|)$, where $|\sigma_i|$ is the order of the permutation $\sigma_i$, which is just its length since it is a cycle. If any of the lengths are the same, then the lcm will be the same,

Ok so far.

> so we may take each $\sigma_i$ to have a different length in our attempt to maximize $|\sigma|$.

Not quite: this says that we should only look at partitions of $5$ into distinct parts, but actually we want to only look at the distinct parts in partitions of $5$ (or equivalently, at partitions of integers *up to* $5$ into distinct parts). You sort-of get away with it for $S_5$, but not necessarily for all symmetric groups.

> This leaves us with four different lengths (I am excluding $1$). Thus $\sigma = \sigma_1 ... \sigma_4$;

Huh? I suppose this *could* make sense if some of the $\sigma_i$ are cycles of zero elements, but that's not the standard cycle decomposition.

> however, as we shall see, it is not possible for $\sigma$ to be a product of 4 disjoint cycles if we are maximizing their lengths.

Indeed. So it would have been more accurate to say that we only need consider partitions for which $k \le 4$. But that's just equivalent to saying that we don't need to consider the partition $1^5$ (or equivalently the identity element of the group); it suffices to observe that the identity element has order one, and in any group other than the trivial group all of the other elements have order greater than one.

> If $\sigma_1$ is a 5-cycle, then none of the 5 numbers will appear in any of the other cycles, and so $\sigma = \sigma_1$ which implies $|\sigma| = 5$.

This should say that if $\sigma_1$ is a 5-cycle then $k=1$ so the LCM is just $\textrm{lcm}(5) = 5$.

> If $\sigma_1$ is a 4-cycle, then 4 of the 5 numbers appear in it, leaving only number left $\sigma_1$ and none to ther others. But this would make $\sigma_2$ and the rest the identity, so that $\sigma = \sigma_1$. In this case $|\sigma| = 4$.

I've just realised that by "*the 5 numbers*" you meant the 5 elements which are permuted. There's an argument to be made that a permutation operates on ordinal numbers in the high-school English sense, moving the ith place to the jth place, but in the interests of clarity it's better to think of a permutation as operating on arbitrary "elements", which might be numbers but might not. Actually, the problem statement explictly talks about "*permutations of five objects*", so that's probably the best phrasing to use in your answer.

I can figure out the intended meaning of the first sentence here from the context, but even correcting the spelling, "*leaving only number left $\sigma_1$ and none to the others*" is not at all clear. What this should say is that if $\sigma_1$ is a 4-cycle, that uses 4 of the 5 objects, leaving only a 1-cycle as $\sigma_2$ and forcing $k=2$. Then the order is $\textrm{lcm}(4, 1) = 4$.

> Finally, if $\sigma_1$ is a 3-cycle, then $\sigma_2$ can have the rest of the numbers which makes it a 2-cycle. In this case, $|\sigma| = lcm(3,2) = 6$.

Replace "numbers" with "objects" and this is better phrased than the earlier cases. But "*Finally*"? You haven't considered partitions as $3+1+1$, $2+2+1$, ...

> By symmetry, the rest of the cases are equivalent, and so the maximum value is $6$.

Symmetry of what? I think that what you mean, and this would have been better stated at the top rather than at the bottom, is that *without loss of generality* we can assume that $|\sigma_1| \ge |\sigma_2| \ge \ldots \ge |\sigma_k|$.