# algebra permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra

Ok, this is rather a question than a problem. So, if we have $\sigma\:\in S_n$ a permutation, why there is a natural number, say $p$, such that $\sigma^p=e$, where $e$ is the identical permutation?

Comment: It would improve your posts of Questions to work out an example or two, so that you can provide Readers with a better indication of where you got with understanding the underlying mechanism, e.g. in this case taking a power of a permutation of $n$ things.

Comment: Is $n$ finite?  (For instance, $n$ could be an infinite cardinal.  There are permutation groups for such sets.)

Answer (score 5):

The set $$\{\sigma,\sigma^2, \sigma^3,...\}$$ is finite so at some points we have $\sigma ^m=\sigma^n$

That is $$\sigma ^{m-n}=e$$

Answer (score 4):

In any finite group every element has finite order by Lagrange. Hence for every $\sigma\in S_n$ there exists a $p$ such that $\sigma ^p=id$. However, the largest possible order of an element in $S_n$ is much smaller than the group order, see here:

[Element of Largest Order in $S_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416253/element-of-largest-order-in-s-n)

Comment: yeah, ok, I forgot to mention that I don t now group theory.

Comment: Lagrange is at the very beginning of group theory, and you don't have to know group theory for it.

Answer (score 1):

One more methodical idea is the following:

Let $\sigma = (a_1a_2\dots a_k)$. Consider $$\sigma^k = (a_1a_2\dots a_k)(a_1a_2\dots a_k)\cdots (a_1a_2\dots a_k).$$ Then 
\begin{align}
a_1 \to a_2 \to &\cdots \to a_k \to a_1,\\
a_2 \to a_3 \to &\cdots \to a_1 \to a_2,\\
&\;\; \vdots\\
a_k \to a_1 \to &\cdots \to a_1 \to a_k,
\end{align}
sending every $a_i$ to itself. Think of this as sort of chaining together $a_i \to a_{i+1}, a_{i+1} \to a_{i+2},\dots$.

An explicit example: If we have $(123)^3 = (123)(123)(123)$, then 
\begin{align}
1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 1\\
2 \to 3 \to 1 \to 2\\
3 \to 1 \to 2 \to 3
\end{align}