# What is the largest order of an element in the group of permutations of $n$ objects?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles, gre-exam

I have a very little knowledge in abstract algebra and want to know what does the problem actually mean.

I encountered this question in the official test

$\text{Graduate Record Examination - Math Subject Test (GR1768) Problem No. 49}$

Which says:

$\text{What is the largest order of an element in the group of permutations of $5$ objects?}$

$\text{(A) }5 \space\space\space\space\space \text{(B) }6 \space\space\space\space\space \text{(C) }12 \space\space\space\space\space \text{(D) }15 \space\space\space\space\space \text{(A) }120$

---

Choice $\text{(B)}$ is the correct one. I do not know how.

Actually I do not want only to know how to solve this, but to understand the theory behind it (in a very simple way).

Could anyone suggest a good reference for this, please?

Or, if possible, to explain briefly the (meaning) of this question.

Note: I already saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416253/element-of-largest-order-in-s-n), but could not help much.

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: See the [Landau Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function)   In this particular case, the product of a transposition and a disjoint $3-$cycle has order $6$.

Comment: The post you link to is the answer to your question. You can't learn all the necessary vocabulary on this site. There is no "very simple way" to explain "the theory behind it". You need the beginning of a course in abstract algebra.

Comment: Answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416253/element-of-largest-order-in-s-n?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: $$\text{Why type like this?}$$